# JUnitResult - get a list of tests executed

Tags: java, junit

I'm using JUnit in a relatively simple workflow

```
JUnitCore runner = new JUnitCore();
m_junitResult = runner.run(m_junitRequest);
```

What I want to achieve is once the execution is over to get the list of all tests executed and their descriptions

Answer (score 2):

i did it with the help of  Junit's RunListner

while running your Junit suites or individual classes make sure you add the listener to it.

```
// AutomationTestSuites - contains my all Junit test classes

 Class cls= AutomationTestSuites.class;


JUnitCore jUnitCore = new JUnitCore();
CustomRunListener customRunListener = new CustomRunListener();
jUnitCore.addListener(customRunListener);

Request request = Request.aClass(cls);
Result result = jUnitCore.run(request);
```

below is my listener

```
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener;
import com.dto.TestSuiteDetails;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.lang.Exception;

public class CustomRunListener extends RunListener{

    private Map<String,TestSuiteDetails> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    private long testSuiteStartTime;
    private long testSuiteElapsedTime;
    private int ignoredCount;


    public void testRunStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
        testSuiteStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }


    public void testStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
        TestSuiteDetails testSuiteDetails = new TestSuiteDetails();
        testSuiteDetails.setTestCaseName(description.getMethodName());
        String[]  arr = description.getTestClass().getName().split("\\.");
        String name = arr[arr.length-1];
        testSuiteDetails.setTestClassName(name);
        String[]  arr1 = name.split("_");
        String testSuite = arr1[0];
        testSuiteDetails.setTestSuiteNmae(testSuite);
        testSuiteDetails.setTestStatus("Passed");
        testSuiteDetails.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        map.put(description.getMethodName(),testSuiteDetails);
    }

    public void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
        TestSuiteDetails testSuiteDetails= null;
        if(map.containsKey(description.getMethodName())){
            testSuiteDetails = map.get(description.getMethodName());
            testSuiteDetails.setElaspsedTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()-testSuiteDetails.getStartTime()));
        }
        map.put(description.getMethodName(),testSuiteDetails);
    }

    public void testRunFinished(org.junit.runner.Result result) throws Exception {
        testSuiteElapsedTime = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()-testSuiteStartTime);
    }

    public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception {
        TestSuiteDetails testSuiteDetails= null;
        if(map.containsKey(failure.getDescription().getMethodName())){
            testSuiteDetails = map.get(failure.getDescription().getMethodName());
        }else{
            testSuiteDetails = new TestSuiteDetails();
        }
        testSuiteDetails.setTestCaseName(failure.getDescription().getMethodName());
        testSuiteDetails.setTestDescription(failure.getException().toString());
        testSuiteDetails.setTestStatus("Failed");
        map.put(failure.getDescription().getMethodName(),testSuiteDetails);
    }

    public void testIgnored(Description description) throws Exception {
        TestSuiteDetails testSuiteDetails= null;
        if(map.containsKey(description.getMethodName())){
            testSuiteDetails = map.get(description.getMethodName());
        }else{
            testSuiteDetails = new TestSuiteDetails();
            testSuiteDetails.setTestCaseName(description.getMethodName());
            String[]  arr = description.getTestClass().getName().split("\\.");
            String name = arr[arr.length-1];
            testSuiteDetails.setTestClassName(name);
            String[]  arr1 = name.split("_");
            String testSuite = arr1[0];
            testSuiteDetails.setTestSuiteNmae(testSuite);
            ignoredCount++;
        }


        testSuiteDetails.setTestStatus("Ignored");
        map.put(description.getMethodName(),testSuiteDetails);
    }

    public int getIgnoredCount() {
        return ignoredCount;
    }

    public void setIgnoredCount(int ignoredCount) {
        this.ignoredCount = ignoredCount;
    }

    public Map<String, TestSuiteDetails> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public long getTestSuiteStartTime() {
        return testSuiteStartTime;
    }

    public long getTestSuiteElapsedTime() {
        return testSuiteElapsedTime;
    }
}
```

am using this pojo for holding test suite details

```
public class TestSuiteDetails {

    private String testClassName;
    private String testSuiteNmae;
    private String testCaseName;
    private String testStatus;
    private String testDescription;

    private long startTime;
    private long elaspsedTime;

    public String getTestClassName() {
        return testClassName;
    }

    public void setTestClassName(String testClassName) {
        this.testClassName = testClassName;
    }

    public String getTestCaseName() {
        return testCaseName;
    }

    public void setTestCaseName(String testCaseName) {
        this.testCaseName = testCaseName;
    }

    public String getTestStatus() {
        return testStatus;
    }

    public void setTestStatus(String testStatus) {
        this.testStatus = testStatus;
    }

    public String getTestDescription() {
        return testDescription;
    }

    public void setTestDescription(String testDescription) {
        this.testDescription = testDescription;
    }

    public long getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(long startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public long getElaspsedTime() {
        return elaspsedTime;
    }

    public void setElaspsedTime(long elaspsedTime) {
        this.elaspsedTime = elaspsedTime;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        TestSuiteDetails that = (TestSuiteDetails) o;

        if (testClassName != null ? !testClassName.equals(that.testClassName) : that.testClassName != null)
            return false;
        return testCaseName != null ? testCaseName.equals(that.testCaseName) : that.testCaseName == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = testClassName != null ? testClassName.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (testCaseName != null ? testCaseName.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    public String getTestSuiteNmae() {
        return testSuiteNmae;
    }

    public void setTestSuiteNmae(String testSuiteNmae) {
        this.testSuiteNmae = testSuiteNmae;
    }
}
```

now after adding the listener - you can simple utilize it later

```
HashMap<String, TestSuiteDetails> myTestResultMap = customRunListener.getMap();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.junit.runner.Result`to get the count of successful test runs.

From doc

> A Result collects and summarizes information from running multiple tests. Since tests are expected to run correctly, successful tests are only noted in the count of tests that ran.

If there are any test failures then you can get description for failures using `org.junit.runner.notification.Failure`

From doc

> A Failure holds a description of the failed test and the exception that was thrown while running it. In most cases the Description will be of a single test. However, if problems are encountered while constructing the test (for example, if a BeforeClass method is not static), it may describe something other than a single test.

Example code

```
// From http://www.tutorialspoint.com/

import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunit.class);
  for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
     System.out.println(failure.toString());
  }
  System.out.println(result.getRunCount());
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, I want to be able to get the test names, rather than the count, which I already have

Comment: If you want test names you have to implement a listener, you can check these links [Example1](http://howtodoinjava.com/junit/how-to-add-listner-in-junit-testcases/) and [Example2](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener).
For [description](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/Description.html) and please edit your question according to what you want.

Comment: For your information **get the list of all tests executed** can be interpreted in many ways, I interpreted that you needed `Result` and `Failures`. You said you already have count but no where in your question its mentioned. 
Anyways editing question is totally on you. The more information you provide in the question the answers will be more precise.